# Как в таблице заменить значение столбца вычисленным значением?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть дерево

id/parent_id/childsCount

childsCount было добавлено для скорости отклика и время от времени должно перекэшироваться. Мне такой подход не нравится, но идея не моя. Так вот, вопрос, как его вычислить, и заполнить?

Сам запрос, который вернет нужные значения выглядит так

```
SELECT *, (SELECT Count(*) FROM TreeTable WHERE Node_Parent_Id = t.Node_Id) ccount FROM 
(SELECT * FROM CatalogOKPD) t
```

В столбце ccount будет актуальное значение. Как перенести его в таблицу?

Можно, конечно, сделать через курсор, пройтись по всем строкам ответа, взять идентификаторы и по ним апдэйтнуть соответствующие строки таблицы... Но, возможно, есть способ без перебора?

Comment: А что, прямо вот такая необходимость хранить количество отдельным полем, c подзапросом очень медленно? Вот такой запрос `select max(cnt), avg(cnt) from (select cnt = count(1) from TreeTable group by Node_Parent_Id) c` что возвращает ?

Comment: @i-one, данных в таблице очень много. Это помимо того, что к серверу и так постоянно идет много запросов. Но я все равно необходимости в этой мере не вижу. Так решил лидер

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
update TreeTable 
set ChildsCount = (select COUNT(*) from TreeTable t WHERE t.Node_Parent_Id = TreeTable.Node_Id)
```

Comment: не работает. Ругается - "Не удалось выполнить привязку составного идентификатора TreeTable.Node_Id"

Comment: update t1
    set t1.ChildsCount = (select COUNT(*) from TreeTable t2 where t2.Node_Parent_Id = t1.Node_Id)
    from TreeTable t1

Answer (score 3):

> Можно, конечно, сделать через курсор, пройтись по всем строкам ответа, взять идентификаторы и по ним апдэйтнуть соответствующие строки таблицы... Но, возможно, есть способ без перебора?

Можно как предложил spv.
Но на будущее я бы создал триггер, который пересчитывал бы количество при изменении данных.

**UPD:** У меня такие триггеры получились:

--таблички:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('I_TreeTableTrigger')IS NOT NULL DROP TRIGGER I_TreeTableTrigger
IF OBJECT_ID('D_TreeTableTrigger')IS NOT NULL DROP TRIGGER D_TreeTableTrigger
IF OBJECT_ID('U_TreeTableTrigger')IS NOT NULL DROP TRIGGER U_TreeTableTrigger
IF OBJECT_ID('TreeTable')IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TreeTable

CREATE TABLE TreeTable(
  Node_Id INT NOT NULL,
  Node_Parent_Id INT,
  ChildCount INT
)

GO
```

--триггеры

```
CREATE TRIGGER U_TreeTableTrigger ON TreeTable 
AFTER UPDATE
AS
  UPDATE T2 
    SET ChildCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TreeTable t WHERE t.Node_Parent_Id = T2.Node_Id)
  FROM TreeTable T2
    JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT CHOOSE(X, id1, id2)Node_Parent_Id
  FROM(VALUES(1),(2))X(X),(
  SELECT i.Node_Parent_Id id1, d.Node_Parent_Id id2
  FROM inserted i
    JOIN deleted d ON i.Node_Id = d.Node_Id AND 
    (i.Node_Parent_Id <> d.Node_Parent_Id OR i.Node_Parent_Id IS NULL OR d.Node_Parent_Id IS NULL))T)d
  ON T2.Node_Id = d.Node_Parent_Id
GO

CREATE TRIGGER D_TreeTableTrigger ON TreeTable 
AFTER DELETE
AS
  UPDATE T2 
    SET ChildCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TreeTable t WHERE t.Node_Parent_Id = T2.Node_Id)
  FROM TreeTable T2
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT d.Node_Parent_Id FROM deleted d)d
    ON T2.Node_Id = d.Node_Parent_Id
GO

CREATE TRIGGER I_TreeTableTrigger ON TreeTable 
AFTER INSERT
AS
  UPDATE T2 
    SET ChildCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TreeTable t WHERE t.Node_Parent_Id = T2.Node_Id)
  FROM TreeTable T2
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT d.Node_Parent_Id FROM inserted d)d
    ON T2.Node_Id = d.Node_Parent_Id

GO
```

--DML операции:

```
INSERT TreeTable VALUES
(1, NULL, 0),
(2, 1, 0),
(3, 2, 0),
(4, 1, 0),
(5, 4, 0),
(6, 5, 0)

UPDATE TreeTable SET Node_Parent_Id = 1 WHERE Node_Id = 5

DELETE TreeTable WHERE Node_Id = 6
```

--результат:

```
SELECT * FROM TreeTable

/* результат:

Node_Id      Node_Parent_Id      ChildCount
1      NULL   3
2      1      1
3      2      0
4      1      0
5      1      0
*/
```

Comment: Я бы тоже так сделал, но увы и ах. Лидер считает, что пересчитывать это надо не в момент обновления, а когда система простаивает.

Comment: @iRumba, но ведь если пересчёт будет производиться асинхронно, то в промежуток времени между фактическим изменением данных и следующим пересчётом информация о количестве дочерних узлов будет не совсем актуальной.